# How to get many field on the Query of webservice

Tags: c#, web-services

I am making a web service get data from sql server. I need to get many fields from the sql server, but I can only get one field, which is the Currancy Name

```
namespace WebApplication2
{
    public class DataHelper
    {
        public static string GetCurrency(string currencyCode)
        {
            string currencyName = "";
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=WEB3\SHAREPOINT;Initial Catalog=WSS_Search_WEB3;Integrated Security=True");
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select PO_NUMBER,PO_STATUS from View_1 where PO_HEADER_ID ='" + currencyCode.ToUpper() + "'", con);
            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                currencyName = dr["PO_NUMBER"].ToString();     
            }
            dr.Close();
            con.Close();
            return currencyName;
        }
    }
}
```

I need to get the PO_Number & PO Status from the Query

Comment: Where is the code?

Comment: on the comment after the detalis

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/55312498/11246623

Comment: so if you need po status just repeat the same steps for po number? else than that what is the problem I can not realy understand what you want?

Comment: Do the same for `PO_STATUS` as you do for `PO_NUMBER`. Did you write that code or are you maintaining it? No offense but it seems pretty obvious you are only extracting one field.

Comment: the problem that on the return method i need to make multi return like the following      (return currencyName;) and also Currency type

Comment: while (dr.Read())
            {
                currencyName = dr["PO_NUMBER"].ToString();     
           currencyType = dr["PO_NUMBER"].ToString();                                                                                                                   
           }
            dr.Close();
            con.Close();
            return currencyName;
        }
    }
}

Comment: Then return an array or an object with those two properties or a tuple or (less optimal) use `out` arguments.

Comment: so can you tell me the code ?

Comment: Have you solved your issue

Comment: no i still i cannot get the second cloum (PO_STATUS)

Comment: [WebMethod]

        public string GetCurrency(string currencyCode)
        {
            return DataHelper.GetCurrency(currencyCode);
        }
    }

Answer (score 1):

As I understand you need to return not only PO_NUMBER, but also PO_STATUS, and as I understand you want to return both values.

I suggest you make model that represent what you want to return.

So for that we make a model class call it for instance POModel:

```
public class POModel
{
    public string currencyName { get; set; } // PO_Number
    public string statusName { get; set; } // PO_Status
}
```

Than fetch the values from SQL as you did and return object in stead of string.

Here would you final code looks like, of course naming and all the stuff you can change the way if fits best:

```
public class DataHelper
{
    public static POModel GetCurrency(string currencyCode)
    {
        //string currencyName = "";
        var poModel = new POModel();
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=WEB3\SHAREPOINT;Initial Catalog=WSS_Search_WEB3;Integrated Security=True");
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select PO_NUMBER,PO_STATUS from View_1 where PO_HEADER_ID ='" + currencyCode.ToUpper() + "'", con);
        con.Open();
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            poModel.currencyName = dr["PO_NUMBER"].ToString();
            poModel.statusName = dr["PO_STATUS"].ToString();
        }
        dr.Close();
        con.Close();
        //return currencyName;
        return poModel;
    }
}

public class POModel
{
    public string currencyName { get; set; }
    public string statusName { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to return an array that contains the two values. Notice `string[]`:

```
public static string[] GetCurrency(string currencyCode)
```

Similar to how you declared `string currencyName = "";`, instead make an array variable:

```
string[] poData = new string[2];
```

Since this looks like it should return a single row, I would not loop. Just do a `Read()`:

```
dr.Read();
poData[0] = dr["PO_NUMBER"].ToString(); //poData[] will have to be declared in your method
poData[1] = dr["PO_STATUS"].ToString();
....
return poData;
```